# How to listen Flash pro actions?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, jsfl

I want to develop plugin to listen Flash's (not Flash Player but when using Flash CC making .fla) actions and do something.

I have learnt jsfl can extend Flash,but it's based on running command by user.Now I want to listen some specific actions such as add new Item into library.So what shall I learn? Can AS  do this ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at `fl.addEventListener()` in the [JSFL reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/extend/flash_cs5_extending.pdf)
You can listen for these events:
"documentNew", "documentOpened", "documentClosed", "mouseMove", "documentChanged", 
"layerChanged", and "frameChanged".

for example:

```
fl.addEventListener("mouseMove",onMouseMove);
function onMouseMove(){
   fl.trace("mouse moved");
}
```

You should also check out [xJSFL](http://www.xjsfl.com/support/api/flash/events). It's pretty handy when scripting Flash.

Comment: I had read xJSFL,It's powerful but heavy and I will pay more time into it.Your answer is so helpful!